# Regexp pattern for dividing string in c#

Tags: c#, regex

I have this string : **"Cooper_Johnson-Biloxi-01-Maqueta_Completa_176.max"**
The thing is that i need to divide it into these variables :

1. client : "Cooper_Johnson"
2. Project : "Biloxi"
3. WIP Number : "01"
4. Scene Name : "Maqueta_Completa"
5. Internal Copy : "176"

I know how to do it via usual string variable - find characters , divide and etc but i really want to learn to use regular expressions for such stuff , and i would like to ask if someone has time to write pattern for this one and describe step by step every part of that pattern.

I used http://gskinner.com/RegExr/ this RegEx tester , it's a really cool thing but i lack knowledge about regex to use it. Also can you recommend any manual about regex ? Maybe some tutorials from easiest to advanced level ?
Thanks a lot in advance !

Comment: I'd recommend [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html). I use it all the time as my go to reference and it offers a very good tutorial.

Comment: My saved "cheat sheet" is: [http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/46/CSharp-Regular-Expressions-Cheat-Sheet](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/46/CSharp-Regular-Expressions-Cheat-Sheet). I would recommend looking into named groups as well. This will allow for cleaner accesses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use named captures:

```
@"^(?<client>[^-]+)-(?<project>[^-]+)-(?<WIP>\d+)-(?<sceneName>.*?)_(?<internalCopy>\d+)\.max$"
```

There is not special things in this pattern:

```
[^-]   character class containing all characters but -

(?<toto>..) named capture (toto here)

^ $    anchors for begining and end of the string

.*?    all characters zero or more times (lazy quantifier)
```

Comment: OP's words: "I know how to do it via usual string variable - find characters , divide and etc but i really want to learn to use regular expressions for such stuff"

Comment: Also not all values in the input are `-` delimited.

Comment: Ok, lets go to a regex solution.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some direction

http://www.RegexHero.com is a good place to test your regex against strings.

[C# Regex Sheet](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/46/CSharp-Regular-Expressions-Cheat-Sheet) is a cheat sheet/guide for c# regex

[Dot Net Perls](http://www.dotnetperls.com/regex-match) here's a good place to start with regex in c#

[MSN Page on Regex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hs600312.aspx)

(But you could use String.Split() and almost have exactly what you want, aside from the last 2)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the links, will check them. Yes i can use the Split but the scope is to learn regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

How about the legendry [RegexLib](http://regexlib.com/). Find, Learn and Cheat Regex